# how to paginate data using Room and RxJava?

Tags: android, pagination, rx-java, android-room

sopuse I have a function in my Room DAO like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cached_tbl ORDER BY id")
    fun getAll(): Flowable<List<Item>>
```

this returns all the items in the database
but I don't want this, I want the data to be paginated and be emitted in little chunks. I want the data to be loaded from the database on demand, for example, 100 items per page. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack has a library for this called Paging which you might be interested in. The good thing about using Room is that it also has Paging integration, so setup will go something like:

Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cached_tbl ORDER BY id")
fun getAll(): PagingSource<Int, Item>
```

ViewModel

```
val pager = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize)) { dao.getAll() }
  .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Activity

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
  pager.flow.collectLatest {
    PagingDataAdapter.submtiData(it)
  }
}
```

You can read quite a bit more here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview, including how to setup a layered source, transformations and more.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but a library is not what I'm looking for

Comment: You can also browse the source in cs.android.com if you want an idea of what you need to hook up, but it essentially works by triggering page loads when adapter requests items by position to bind, and sending the right list update callbacks.